# Pre-increment and post-increment operators in Swift

Tags: swift

```
 //Post and Pre-Increment Test
   func FindValueOFC() -> String
    {
        var a : Int = 10
        var b : Int = 20
        var c = a++ + a++ + b++ + b++ + ++a + ++b
        return "The value Of variable C is \(c)"
    }

    let whatsTheValueOfC = FindValueOFC()
    println(whatsTheValueOfC)
```

Why does this program prints out `The value Of variable C is 98`?
Logically it should be 96, as `a++ + a++ + b++ + b++ + ++a + ++b` can be translated to `10+11+20+21+12+22 = 96`

Comment: ++ has been removed in Swift3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't **ever** do this in a real program. It leads to *undefined behavior* when you mix multiple mutators in the same expression. There is nothing in the language that guarantees that the *pre-increment operator* happens immediately before the value is accessed or that the *post-increment* operator happens immediately after the variable is accessed.

The compiler could have done the pre-increment of `a` and `b` first, added up all of the values, and then applied the post-increments. This would have given the result of

```
11 + 11 + 21 + 21 + 11 + 21 = 96
```

The point being that many answers are possible and valid, hence the name *undefined behavior*.  It is possible that you would get different answers with different levels of compiler optimization, which could lead to very puzzling differences between your testing and shipping versions of your app.

Comment: Also, the compiler could evaluate it from the right or even change the order of additions...